# Android: nested linearlayouts error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create, as a test, a row of three images (evenly spaced with a vertical orientation) in the top half of my screen. For some reason, android:layout_height="0dp" is giving me an error, saying it will make the view invisible. It is right of course, I can't see a thing. Why is that the case? I changed the weight to 1, so why isn't it expanding to take up the space available? Thanks!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">





<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/arches_utah"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_sea_mountains"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/china_jungle"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `layout_weight` on an element applies to the parent of said element. Since you parent element has a horizontal orientation, you can only use `layout_weight` paired with `layout_width`. If your root `LinearLayout` was a `vertical` then you could set the `layout_height` to be `0dp` and use `layout_weight` instead.

Judging by your question, it sounds like you should be setting weights and height on the three elements within the first child `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The weight attribute needs to be specified on the same axis as the orientation of the parent. Since your parent `LinearLayout` has a horizontal orientation, the `weight` attribute works on the width, so you need `layout_height="wrap_content"` and `layout_width="0dp"` on the child `LinearLayout`.

So the problem is between your 2 `LinearLayouts`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your parent Linear Layout and layout width relate weight not height...You can also use `weightSum` like this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="2" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/arches_utah" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_sea_mountains" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/china_jungle" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```